# How do I stop 1 .sh file from another?

Tags: shell

I ran something like this code below:

```
sh example.sh;sh playmusic.sh
```

Inside playmusic.sh is an mpg123 command playing music. I set it to loop 1000 times (so that I make sure that the other shell script is done before the music stops playing). But when the other shell script is done, how do I stop playmusic.sh?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to launch both scripts into the background:

```sh
sh example.sh &
example_pid=$!

sh playmusic.sh &
play_pid=$!

wait $example_pid
kill $play_pid
```

---

inside playmusic.sh, try this to stop playing music when the script exits:

```sh
# however you invoke mpg123, try putting it in the background
mpg123 arg arg arg &
mpg123_pid=$!
trap 'kill $mpg123_pid' EXIT
wait
```

Show what you're doing in playmusic.sh if this isn't immediately helpful.

Comment: it doesn't stop playing the music.

Comment: @HilmBlahh : You did not show, how you invoked your `mpg123` from your script, so we can't say whether killing the script is enough. Perhaps the player is run in the background? The idea, which glenn jackman sketched here, is however correct: You need to send an appropriate signal to the player to stop it.